# How someone can get any siddhi from Lord Hanuman?

Tags: hanuman, siddhi

First let me tell you who and what I am as a devotee because that might help you to give my answer.

I am devotee of Shree Ram and Lord Hanuman. I am small devotee, not any major one. But as a devotee I want to increase my level in eyes of my Lord so that I can also get moksha.
To achieve this righ now I am doing fasts (Vrata) of Lord Hanuman since few months and I am willing to continue this fasts until my last breath. Means, as long as I am alive, I will keep doing fasts on Tuesday for Lord Hanuman.

As I am devotee of Shree Ram also (Both are so close to my heart), so I am doing Satya Narayan Fast also on every purnima since months. And this fast of Narayan, also willing to continue till end of my life. Never gonna quit...
I can't say that I don't have any greed in doing these fasts although I am also human that can go selfish sometimes. But my biggest greed is Moksha. That's why I am doing this.

But here I am only for Lord Hanuman right now. So let's come to real question. I heard that Lord Hanuman blesses their true devotee with some sidhies. He is one of the few Lord who gives sidhi/power to their devotee (not completely clear on that point).As per my knowledge, Mata Kali and Lord Hanuman use to give sidhies to thier devotees. So what I want to know is, how one can get any siddhi from Lord Hanuman? Is there any mantra that can help to pleased Lord Hanuman or any other way through which Lord Hanuman will give blessing to their devotee in form of any siddhi?

Comment: Patanjali Yoga Sutras mention methods for getting those Siddhis. Do you want Siddhis only by blessing of Hanuman or by any way?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Since I am devotee of Lord Hanuman, so I can't accept siddhi from any other lord (Narayana is exception). I want it only from my Lord.

Comment: Ok. But no one gives Siddhis when you do Yoga. You get it when you do it (obviously, under guidance of a Guru).

Comment: @TheDestroyer But in my busy schedule of day, I can't find any Guru. As par my past incident I believe Lord Hanuman give me a hint that I want to give you siddhi, thats why I got inspired to get one. May be I missunderstood that incident and that incident was not an hint from my Lord or may be it was. Who can know? But in any case What can I do?

Comment: One way of doing it is doing Purascharana of any Hanuman mantra after taking it from Guru.. Purascharana is a tedious process and if u can perform it as per Vidhis u may get Hanuman's vision and blessings in the form of siddhis. Siddhis are not obtained easily..One has to do quite a good amount of penance..Are u ready for it?

Comment: Tulsidas says in hanuman chalisa that lord hanuman get boon from Sita to give siddhi

Comment: @Rickross Right now I am not sure, what level of penance I can do but I want to try it. And about Mantra, I don't have any Guru from whom I can get any Hanuman Mantra. If you know any Mantra of Lord Hanuman then let me know.

Comment: If you are serious then u should first get initiation of any Hanuman mantra from a Guru.. The first requirement for mantra sadhana is Guru diksha.. Only then u can achieve ur goals..Purascharana can not be done without Guru diksha..I can tell u about many mantras..even u can urself get them from internet, but by chanting them u'll not get the desired effects. Also a sadhaka obtains sidhis only after years of penance. So its not that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jai Shree Ram!* This Mantra **"अष्ट-सिद्धि नव निधि के दाता । अस बर दीन जानकी माता।।**  clearly states that Lord Hanuman have all these 8 Siddhis and he is also able to give these Siddhis to his devotees.

To Answer your question i would like to describe about these Siddhis. There are Ashta (8) Siddhis which are very similar to Supernatural powers. But, It`s really not easy to get these Siddhis by chanting Mantras only! As its extremely rare and very difficult to find such mantra and the saadhna of that Mantra.

> These are The eight siddhis: anima (the power to assimilate oneself
>   with an atom); mahima (the power to expand oneself into space);
>   laghima (the power to be as light as cotton or any similar thing);
>   garima (the power to be as heavy as anything); prapti (the power of
>   reaching anywhere, even to the moon); prakamya (the power of having
>   all wishes, of whatever description, realized); isvata (power to
>   create); vasvita (power to command all).

Watch this video which describes all of Ashta Siddhis in Hindi: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAlg9SI-8tg

It`s Really Hard! Though, if you truly want to attain any of these siddhis you can try deep Sadhana to attain these Siddhis which are also called as spiritual advancement.

It`s Hard to find the exact process or Mantras to get these Ashta Siddhis from Lord Hanuman. Though, there is a Mantra Saadhna from "Shree Hanumat Beesa Yantra", which only works for devoted Hanuman Bhakts. You can try the below Mantra with the procedure mentioned here in this [link](http://www.prophet666.com/2016/06/hanuman-mantra-to-get-ashta-siddhi-and.html). This is a kind of Hanuman Mantra Sadhana which brings the Hanuman Bhakt close to  Lord Hanuman and Help to get Ashta Siddhis.

**Mantra**

> || ॐ ह्रां ह्रीं ह्रूं ह्रें ह्रों हँ: श्री हनुमते नमः रं राम भक्त हं
>   हनुमंता सर्व सिद्धि प्रदः सर्व संकटादि नाशकः अं अंजनिपुत्र आंजनेय मम
>   सहाय कुरु कुरु स्वाहा ||

These Asht Siddhis are also mentioned in Patanjali's Yoga Sutras IV: 1, Patanjali mentions ways to attain these supernatural powers. You can also do the deep sadhna "Bandhas in Yoga" which is a "secret" aspects of Yoga.

> It can be translated roughly as breathing exercises. After the body
>   has been prepared by thorough practice in the different asanas and
>   clarified by the breathing exercises, the Yogi is ready for the
>   Bandhas. These may not be attained immediately, since they depend on a
>   full state of body and mental relaxation for successful attainment.

You can read all these "Bandhas" here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rwy/rwy09.htm

Finally, and beyond the siddhis, comes the grand result of mukti, or emancipation from rebirth, and the conscious.