# How did Hanuman get the 8-Siddhis and 9-Nidhis?

Tags: hanuman, siddhi

What should one do to achieve  8-Siddhis and 9-Nidhis?

Comment: Don't run after siddhis, they won't come if thats the main objective of sadhana.

Comment: He has since his birth because he is Shivansh.

Comment: [How someone can get any siddhi from Lord Hanuman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-someone-can-get-any-siddhi-from-lord-hanuman). In mentioned post, read all comments also, not just answer. Because comments was extremely helpful too.